# Is there a way to use typescript variable in html files?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I use a variable defined in a typescript file of a component, in my index.html file in angular 4?

Comment: `<p>{{nameOfVariable}}</p>`

Comment: @messerbill, but only if the name of the variable is "nameOfVariable" :D

Comment: and so far your `<app-root></app-root>` is called in your `index.html` you cannot access any variables out of the app. Use `app.component.html` instead

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use this in index.html directly but you can use this by assigning the value in a component.ts file like

yourvariable : string;

and use this variable only in a component.html file which is been of the same type.

like `{{yourvariable}}`

you can also access this variable to any component.

in angular index.html is the starting point of view in which there is component based div structure. you can add variable there using above procedure.